# check radio buttons and fields to enable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, forms

I have a form with a lot of radio buttons and a couple of text fields. So...

```
<input type="radio" name="pic" id="pic" value="val1">
<input type="radio" name="pic" id="pic" value="val2">
<input type="radio" name="pic" id="pic" value="val3">

<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
<input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="">
```

and there's a link after the form that will open up a lightbox. I want the link to be enabled only if a radio button is selected and the two fields are filled out. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id` (it's invalid (x)html, an `id` must be unique within the document). Use a `class` instead.

Comment: Addinf to @David I think this will help you out: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should work:

```
if ($('input:radio[name=pic]:checked').length && $('#email').val().length && $('#comment').val().length) {
    /* activate the lightbox link */
}

else {
    alert("Please ensure you've selected one of the radio buttons, and filled out the text-fields.");
}
```

---

**Edited** to amend your code:

#### html:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="pic" id="pic" value="val1">
    <input type="radio" name="pic" id="pic" value="val2">
    <input type="radio" name="pic" id="pic" value="val3">

    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(

function() {
    if ($('input:radio[name=pic]:checked').length && $('#email').val().length && $('#comment').val().length) { /* activate the lightbox link */
    }
    else {
        alert("Please ensure you've selected one of the radio buttons, and filled out the text-fields.");
    }
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/zwkrD/).

Comment: this is little complicated isnt it?

Comment: @fehergeri, yeah. Um, maybe...it's late, I'm tired..? I...should stop talking now, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#link").click(function(e) {
    if ($('input[name=pic]:checked').val() && $('#email').val() && $('#comment').val()) lightbox();
    else e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checklink() {
    if ($('[name=pic]').val()) && $('#email').val() && $('#comment').val()) {
        $('#linkId').hide();
    } else {
       $('#linkId').show()
}
```

then add `onchange="checklink()"` to your input fields

**Edit**: fixed disabling as per @fehergeri comment